# Is token volatility an issue for the data marketplace?

Tags: data-marketplace

Will the extreme price volatility of IOTA tokens, and cryptocurrencies in general, make it impractical to use in the **data marketplace** when it goes mainstream? I can imagine the non-crypto-literate average Joe being very unhappy to know that the money he got for his data is now half of what he expected it to be.

What workaround is possible in this scenario?

Comment: The only workaround that I can think of is auto-instant conversion to fiat, but not sure if that is possible, considering the small amount of money involved per data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative answer to this question is that IOTA's primary current vision is a machine to machine economy. The machine to machine economy may not have any need for conversion to FIAT, and will generate a more stable IOTA value over time. It is likely that if the machine economy becomes big enough and IOTA is adopted enough, that the value of IOTA will become far more stable over time relative to FIAT (similar to how USD is somewhat stable relative to other currencies such as GBP, JPY).

If IOTA is adopted with enough amounts of use, then it will be accepted as a form of payment without any conversion to FIAT necessary, which will further cement its purchasing power and value.

Answer (score 3):

Even with small amounts of IOTA **instant conversion to FIAT** (or any other stable cryptocurrency) would be possible (e.g. you can  sell single IOTAs on exchanges at the current price but you can only withdraw after you have $10)

All exchanges I know only display FIAT with 2 decimal place accuracy currently but it would be easy to implement any amount of decimal places.

In future it would probably also be possible to open a [Flash Channel](https://flash.tangle.works) together with an exchange to transfer even smaller amounts without doing the POW.